# Program successfully installed but not displayed on device

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have just started programming on nexus 5 phone and sony smartwatch. I tired to install a sample program (HelloLayouts) on the device and it shows the following msg:

```
[HelloLayouts] Uploading HelloLayouts.apk onto device '.......'
[HelloLayouts] Installing HelloLayouts.apk... [HelloLayouts] Success!
[HelloLayouts] \HelloLayouts\bin\HelloLayouts.apk installed on device
[HelloLayouts] Done!
```

I checked applications from Smart connect but it doesn't show any installed program name hellolayoputs. I also checked the smartwatch, but didn't see any installed application. Not sure if I am missing anything.

any suggestion to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: But please be more specific. Just from the console output nobody can tell you what's wrong. The app manigest would be helpfull.

Comment: Not sure if the issue is with manifest file. I installed two other sample program ("Hello Sensors" and "Hello Notifications") and these apps are working properly.

Comment: What exactly does 'not displayed' mean? Is the app not beeing launched or isn't it even visible on the homescreen?

Comment: I have the same not visible in SmartConnect or Home screen on watch. My current version in Play works, only changed the icons, made an update now with Android Studio. Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few questions:

- Did you modify the HelloLayouts sample file at all or did you just run the sample right after installing it? If you did modify it try creating a new sample from scratch and running it again.
- Are you running your samples with Eclipse, or Android Studio, etc...?
- Are you using the latest Android SDK v 23.0.2?

Also you may want to try restarting your phone and watch to see if you can at least see the app showing up in the SmartWatch 2 app.

Comment: 1. no, I didn't modify HelloLayouts. I just make sure that the two libraries are added (SmartExtensionAPI, SmartExtensionUtils) in the project.
2. With Eclipse
3. Yes, using latest SDK

Comment: I installed two other sample program ("Hello Sensors" and "Hello Notifications") and these apps are working properly. However, HelloLayout is not working

Comment: ok. Are you using Sony Add-on SDK 2.0 or 3.0? Have you tried restarting your watch and phone? Also check your list of apps and be sure that the app exists. If it does try uninstalling it and then running it in eclipse again.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am using SDK 3.0 with a smartwatch (not smartwatch 2). I found the app in the apps list, unstall that and run the program from eclipse again. the program appear in the apps list again, but doesn't show in Smart Connect or in the smartwatch.

Comment: oh you are developing for the SmartWatch 1. I believe that you might have more success with add on SDK 2.0. Can you try that out and see if it works?

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your suggestion. I will switch the SDK to 2.0. is there any link to download/install in eclipse?

Comment: Hmm.. Looks like it is not up right now. I will see if I can find it online for you. If not I can always send it to you directly.

Comment: Hi again MKS. My apologies as it turns out if you want to develop for the SmartWatch 1 that you can still use the 3.0 SDK, but you should use the "BackwardsCompatible" Sample as your base. Please let me know if you have any more questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

May be Launcher Activity is missing or corresponding 'category' tag is missing from 'intent-filter' of launcher activity your Android Manifest file. Check it or post your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Not sure if the issue is with manifest file. I installed two other sample program ("Hello Sensors" and "Hello Notifications") and these apps are working properly.